# What does java stringvars means?

Tags: java

I am a java beginner and I would like to ask question
What does package **stringvars** means in java?

```
package stringvars;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class myProg{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String first_name; //packge stringvars
        System.out.print("Kindly Enter your first name: ");
        first_name = user_input.next();

        String family_name; //packge stringvars
        System.out.print("Enter your family name: ");
        family_name = user_input.next();

        String full_name; //packge stringvars
        full_name = first_name + " " + family_name;

        System.out.println("I Guess you are " + full_name);

    }

}
```

and also I get error when I try to run java

[image]

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow! Your question can be improved in several ways: first, the package question and error ar two diferent questions, so you should make two different post. Secondly, you shouldn"t use a picture but add a snippet of code and his error instead

Comment: Hmm what is the purpose of that package hihihi i just copy that source code and try to understand and run

Comment: To run your code try: `java -cp . kaganovich`.

Comment: Are you required to use the CMD? Or can you install an IDE?

Comment: we are required to use cmd for now in our second semester we will use netbeans Thank you for answering my question sir it helps me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Since you are declaring a package as

```
package stringvars;
```

Your java class should be inside *stringvars* folder. Than you can try to compile and run.

Comment: Thank you sir/maam it works hihihi

Comment: Haha I am a guy. Glad to hear that.